# There was an error running the selected generator: Package restore failed.Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject' (Asp.net core Project Error))

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

While I want to add scaffolded Item in my asp.net core project

add>New Scaffolded item > Identity > MarkAll>

Adding Layout And DbContext > Add

Visual Studio 2019 shows me a Error Message

***There was an error running the selected generator:  Package restore failed.Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject'***

My DbContext Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using UdbService.Models;

namespace UdbService.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Service { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkBFT.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0KfP.png)

Comment: Try to update all your nuget-package in your project.

Comment: After I Update All nuget packages It works. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

After I Update Following nu-get packages The Error Message are not showing any more.

**I update Following NU-Get packages ***serially***

**

1.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

2.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver

3.Microsoft.AspNetcore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

4.Microsoft.AspNetcore.Identity.UI